# Remove "componentheading" from homepage - Joomla!

Tags: joomla

I'm working on a site in Joomla! and on the homepage, at the top of the article, it comes up with a h1 of the website name. The pagesource says  (Note it's not the article title.)

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Thanks,
Steph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this h1 tag not to display via the Parameters - System section of your Menu Item Manager screen in administrator ... [this page](http://www.joomlashack.com/tutorials/249-how-to-remove-welcome-to-the-frontpage) has a nice depiction of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

It's so simple

Just do the following :

1. Login  to the Joomla Administrator Interface
2. Go to the Menu Manager
3. Select your Menu
4. Select your Menu Item (**Home Menu**)
5. On the right hand, Click *Parameters (System)—>* and in the *Show Page Title—->*Just Select No.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the desired solution, since many people, (including myself) actually need to be able to Set/Override the page title (That Appears in the Browser’s Title bar), and setting Page Title to no here will also remove the functionality to Configure the Browser title (which is important for SEO among other things).

Anyway, I have searched and not been able to find a fully correct solution via CMS or PHP Code. The closest solution which is not fully perfect, but unlikely to cause significant (if any) negative effect on your site is through Javascript (Example is JQuery).

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $(‘.componentheading’).empty();
});
```

This can also be done is JS with no JQuery. When I find a better method of doing this I’ll let you know.This should actually be done by removing output from a template file.I don’t know which one yet. When I do, I’ll post it…

Answer (score 0):

When setting the page title not to show in the menu item as stated in other answers, this will not stop the text entered in the page title box being used as the browser title, it will just stop it being shown in the page.

Using javascript to remove it is not a good idea.
1. It will only work for browsers with javascript enabled
2. Search engine spiders will still see it. As the component heading for articles is 'articles' by default it will see all your pages with the same h1 tag.

Just turn it off in the menu item and enter your browser title in the text box above.